# javascript unexpected token < , is there any way I can escape the errors(or atleast skip those useless characters)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In php, I have an array like this :

```
$arr['a'] = "some big data so may contain some chars that bring us headache"
$arr['b'] = "some big data same as above"

$data = json_encode($arr)
echo $data
```

My javascript code containing a jquery ajax call, $.ajax . It calls the file containing the above php code so, on success, the json_encoded(by php) is returned to my javascript variable . In my javascript file, I am doing like this :

```
jsdata = JSON.parse(data); //Getting error here

$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: jsdata,
url: "url",
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(d) {
  print("success");
});
```

From the above code, in the line jsdata = JSON.parse(data), I am getting errors something like

```
  Error :    UNEXPECTED TOKEN <
```

As the data contains lot of different content, its normal to get those errors . They need to be escaped properly . Can anyone tell me how to do that correctly . Whatever the data may be , I shouldnot get error regarding the data .

Thanks

Comment: json_encode should be escaping any data correctly. You must have something else in your output causing problems.  Have you checked to see exactly what output you're getting?

Comment: Does your file start with `<<?php` instead of `<?php`?

Comment: I had a similar issue, which was caused by PHP running with the option display errors = On. When the PHP script then echoed some error, Javascript issued the "Unexpected token...". Try calling the php file directly in the browser and see what you get, perhaps this helps.

Comment: this comment is the answer . I got error from php . Thanks man, and thanks to others also . By the way, what should I mark as answer .

Answer (score 4):

Well, a couple of things you should probably know `jsdata = JSON.parse(data);` tries to parse whatever *json string* you assigned to `data`, and return it as a JS object. I think you want to do the opposite: `jsdata = JSON.stringify(data);`

Besides, since you are using jQuery, you could just leave that line out: jQuery will convert the data to the appropriate format before sending the request anyway, no need to bother with *parsing or stringify-ing* it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you forgot the `;` at the end of two lines, so PHP is outputing an error, which is no JSON-compliant.

Always do this :

- Catch errors and output them in a way that is understable by your application (a 5xx status can be enough)
- Next time you have this, use Chrome Developper tool or Firebug to see what your app really returns
- Also, you're outputing json, not jsonp which is different and what your app expects

Comment: the error occurs even before the call to the php file is made, I recon the semicolon is either a typo or the next bug the OP will encounter :)

Comment: i think that php part is only for demonstration and not his actual code.

Comment: It is probably not actual code but the other advices still stand ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  data: jsdata,
  url: "url",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(d) {
    print("success");
  }
})
```

try it this way

Answer (score 0):

This is much more simple than it might seem.

Call `urlencode($arr['a'])` and `urlencode($arr['b'])` (for each data value in `$arr`) before encoding the JSON and echoing `$data` to the JavaScript. This will [URL-Encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the data in the array so that it will cause you no problems.

When you are done parsing the JSON, you will have to call the JavaScript function `unescape(string)` on each of the large data values. This will return them to the way they originally were. It's a sort of superhero-team-up of PHP and JavaScript!